# Sort objects in array based on two keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, sorting

I have a JavaScript array that looks like the one below and I am trying to sort the elements based on Ptr and Outputs. The correct ordering is: (Node 0 -> Node 2 -> Node 1). The Output of an element should be the same as the Ptr of the next element. I'm not sure how to do this in JS as I am new to the language.

```
nodeObjs = [{
  Node: '0',
  Id: '8057358647298',
  Ptr: '2454369535744',
  Outputs: '2454369536096',
  Type: 'SrcStream',
  NodeDetails: 'MediaType=[FrameSize=8246337209332 (1920,1012),BitRate=3733169,Compressed=1,MajorType={73646976-0000-0010-8000-00AA00389B71},Stride=0,Rotation=0,FrameRate=42949672960397843 (10000000,397843),PixelAspectRatio=4294967297 (1,1),InterlacedMode=7,Subtype={34363248-0000-0010-8000-00AA00389B71}]'
},
{
  Node: '1',
  Id: '8057358647297',
  Ptr: '2454369537680',
  Outputs: '',
  Type: 'Out',
  NodeDetails: 'MediaType=[FrameSize=8246337209332 (1920,1012),BitRate=3733169,Compressed=0,MajorType={73646976-0000-0010-8000-00AA00389B71},Stride=1920,Rotation=0,FrameRate=42949672960397843 (10000000,397843),PixelAspectRatio=4294967297 (1,1),InterlacedMode=7,Subtype={3231564E-0000-0010-8000-00AA00389B71}]'
},
{
  Node: '2',
  Id: '8057358647303',
  Ptr: '2454369536096',
  Outputs: '2454369537680',
  Type: 'Trnsfrm',
  NodeDetails: 'CLSID={62CE7E72-4C71-4D20-B15D-452831A87D9D},HWMFT=0,InputType=[FrameSize=8246337209332 (1920,1012),BitRate=3733169,Compressed=1,MajorType={73646976-0000-0010-8000-00AA00389B71},Stride=0,Rotation=0,FrameRate=42949672960397843 (10000000,397843),PixelAspectRatio=4294967297 (1,1),InterlacedMode=7,Subtype={34363248-0000-0010-8000-00AA00389B71}],OutputType=[FrameSize=8246337209332 (1920,1012),BitRate=3733169,Compressed=0,MajorType={73646976-0000-0010-8000-00AA00389B71},Stride=1920,Rotation=0,FrameRate=42949672960397843 (10000000,397843),PixelAspectRatio=4294967297 (1,1),InterlacedMode=7,Subtype={3231564E-0000-0010-8000-00AA00389B71}]'
}]
```

Comment: You should write here what did you try so far. First result from google "javascript sort" will show you the correct answer which is a [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). Try to do it by yourself. If you will fail then write what you tried and what problems you still have. Good luck!

Comment: 1) Is it always Node 0 that sets the order, and 2) what happens if no node has Node 0's Output?

Comment: Any chance that `Type` also indicates an ordering (SrcStream > Trnsfrm > Out)?

Comment: @jarmod Type does indicate some ordering but the issue is that there can be multiple Trnsfrms. The example above is simplistic in that there are only 3 nodes.

Comment: @RickardElimää Whichever node is SrcStream sets the order. Don't worry about the edge case where no node has Node 0's output.

Answer (score -1):

using ES6:

```
nodeObjs.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.Outputs.localeCompare(b.Ptr) && b.Node - a.Node;
}).reverse()
```

Comment: This resulted in the correct ordering for the example above. However the actual values of Ptr and Outputs doesn't matter. They can be any integer and their linking only depends on whether Ptr === Output. I can provide another example where this code doesn't result in the correct ordering.